# Using Grunt.js to copy all HTML files from one directory structure to another

Tags: build, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I have a large directory structure, typical of most apps.

For example, like this:

```
theprojectroot
|- src
|     |- app
|     |     |- index.html
|     |     |- index.js
|     |     |- userhome
|     |     |     |- userhome.html
|     |     |     |- userhome.js
|     |     |- management
|     |     |     |- management.html
|     |     |     |- management.js
|     |     |- social
|     |     |     |- social.html
|     |     |     |- social.js
|     |- assets
|- vendor
|- package.json
```

I would like to copy all the `HTML` files - and **ONLY** the HTML files - in all the directories into another folder.

I'm currently using Grunt `copy` to copy all files, but now I'd like to do so just for the HTML. [In the docs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy), there doesn't seem to be any option to select a file type.

Does anyone have a hack they could suggest to do this?

Comment: After some tinering, I've discovered that `src: '**/**.html'` does what I'm looking for. I just don't understand why. So if someone can explain, I will accept their answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code will work

```
copy: {
    files: {
        cwd: 'path/to/files',  // set working folder / root to copy
        src: '**/*.html',      // copy all files and subfolders **with ending .html**
        dest: 'dist/files',    // destination folder
        expand: true           // required when using cwd
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The flatten: true option as in this answer might work for some cases, but it seems to me that the more common requirement (as in my case) is to copy a folder and its sub-folder structure, as-is, to    dest. It seems that in most cases if you have sub-folders, they are probably being referenced that way in code. The key to doing this is the cwd option, which will preserve folder structure relative to the specified working directory:

```
copy: {
  files: {
    cwd: 'path/to/files',  // set working folder / root to copy
    src: '**/*.html',      // copy only html files
    dest: 'dist/files',    // destination folder
    expand: true           // required when using cwd
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you missed what I'm asking. I would to copy ONLY `html` files and not other files in the directory. Perhaps I should update the question